# Bypassing squid for certain domains

Tags: http, proxy, squid

I'm trying to use a squid proxy to redirect HTTP to an upstream proxy, however a handful of domains should go direct.

Traffic via the upstream proxy is working as expected, but if I access [www.example.org](http://www.example.org) I get a 403, without seeing any request go to the origin server, or anything useful in the logs.

One thing worth noting, I'm using a DNS server that replies to all requests with the IP of the proxy in order to route requests to the proxy. For requests made directly to IP addresses I'm using DSTNAT rules on the router.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? Thanks

```
#debug_options ALL,2

# ACL definitions

acl localnet src 127.0.0.1
acl rfc_1918 src 10.0.0.0/8
acl rfc_1918 src 172.16.0.0/12
acl rfc_1918 src 192.168.0.0/16
acl protoweb src 100.80.13.0/24
acl direct_sites dstdomain .example.org

# Listen directives
http_port 3128
http_port 0.0.0.0:8080 intercept

# Only allow localhost to access the squid management interface
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# Only allow private and Dial-Up clients to connect to proxy
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow rfc_1918
http_access allow protoweb
http_access allow direct_sites
http_access deny all

always_direct allow direct_sites
never_direct allow !direct_sites

cache_peer wayback.protoweb.org parent 7851 0 no-query proxy-only
```

I have tried various permutations of the config file with little success.